# Does The Classical Limit of Quantum Computing Exists?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, semiclassical

In any standard college book on quantum mechanics and field theory, one for sure has encountered some expressions like " the classical limit corresponds to setting hbar to zero" or quantum loops are coming in powers of hbar etc.. However, in the context of quantum computing, it is unclear how the mapping from quantum to classical computing may be quantified?
(also, the term "setting hbar to zero" is unprecise but can be used for most of cases at the level of students to understand). In geometric quantization schemes, we may multiply poisson brackets with some quantity proportional to -ihbar

What is the limit where the quantum computation theory reduces to classical?

Comment: The classical physics therories are not subsets of the quantum.  Classical mechanics **emerges** from quantum. Think of the completely classical case where it can be shown mathematically that thermodynamics emerges from statistical mechanics.

Comment: @anna v thanks for your comment. I meant that the solutions of quantum dynamical equations. For example, the loop expansion in quantum field theory contains the classical part plus one loop which is quantum etc...so classical solutions exists in the context of quantum theory. In any case, the main question was to quantum computing

Comment: Quantum computing is based on qubits, which are as un-classical as you can possibly get, so I don't think the question makes sense. The only regime where a qubit behaves classically is one where it actually isn't a qubit at all (a rather different situation from the limit of quantum field theory to classical field theory).

Comment: More on [classical limit in QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bquantum-mechanics%5D+%5Bsemiclassical%5D+%5Bclassical-mechanics%5D+limit).

Comment: @knzhou One could claim that the classical computing corresponds to bits which are exactly determined and quantum computing corresponds to qubits or in principles quantum objects which are probabilistic; the limit where the probabilistic nature collapses correspond to the limit of classicality

Comment: @annav No, classical physics came first. Quantum theory emerged from classical theory, driven by phenomena that classical physics couldn't accommodate, but the quantum theory is fundamentally constrained by the phenomena of classical physics. In physics, theories come along (and occasionally disappear), but the phenomena are the solid foundation.

Comment: If you have $N$ generic quantum degrees of freedom, it's perfectly sensible to ask how under generic conditions those degrees of freedom reproduce a classical limit. A big part of the story is decoherence. However, quantum computing is a specifically engineered *non-generic* set of conditions where the degrees of freedom are manipulated to form a coherent superposition. So while you can ask about how classical behavior emerges from a large quantum system, this limit will necessarily take you out of the regime where that system behaves like a quantum computer.

Comment: @JohnDoty I am not talking of the history of theories.  Of course the classical came firs. BUT the current standard model of particle physics ,  in mainstream physics, , can be shown to connect smoothly with classical theories which emerge at the limits of the region of validity of the mathematics of QFT

Comment: @annav It isn't simply history: every observation you make is presented to you through physical senses. Those senses don't emerge from the theory: the theory emerges from those senses, enhanced in various ways. Only in mathematics does the theory emerge from fundamental axioms. Mathematics isn't physics: it is one of the tools we use to enhance our senses.

Comment: @JohnDoty  sure, but the QFT mathematics is very successfull , was chosen to contain the emergence of the historical theories, chosen because the conservation laws of classical physics were axiomatically incorporated into QFT

Comment: @annav Exactly. So the theory emerged from the historical theories, not the other way around. The foundations are in the phenomena: calling the phenomena emergent is to reverse cause and effect.

Comment: @JohnDoty I am not calling the phenomena emergent. I am saying that in the qunatum mechanical modeling theory the phenomena can be treated as emergent, in the mathematics. And at present the theory fits data and observations.

Answer (score 2):

"Gate-based" quantum computers are the analog of digital classical computers. Classical computers implement logic gates such as AND, NOT, OR, XOR, NAND. Quantum computers can implement these gates but they can implement other gates. A typical example is the $\sqrt{\text{NOT}}$ gate. this is a gate which negates the quantum bit when applied twice. There is no analog for the $\sqrt{\text{NOT}}$ gate in classical digital computing. Furthermore, the existence of the $\sqrt{\text{NOT}}$ gate is a discrete fact. That is, there's not some knob we can tune that makes the $\sqrt{\text{NOT}}$ gate gradually go away until we recover classical computing with no such gate.

So the answer to your question is a flat "no". No, there is no "classical limit" of gate-based quantum computing. In fact, digital quantum computers function based on **exactly** the components of quantum mechanics that have no classical analog. For example spin $N$ systems with large $N$ are approximately like classical rotors, but quantum computers use spin 1/2 systems which behave maximally quantum mechanically. In quantum mechanics and classical computers there can be correlations between different bits, but quantum computers heavily leverage entanglement, a type of correlation which is impossible classically. In other words, digital quantum computing gets it's power precisely because it has no classical analog.

On the other hand, there are so-called "quantum simulators" in in which medium sized quantum systems are isolated and studied in fine detail to help us better understand other similar, larger and more applicable quantum systems. In this case we don't have control of every individual degree of freedom like in a digital quantum computer, but we have enough isolation and control that we can study something interesting. I like to call such simulators "analog quantum computers". An example of an "analog classical computer" is a wind tunnel. We can't always solve the Navier-Stokes equation, but we can build a wing and blow wind over it to see how the wing performs. We create a physical scenario, click "go", watch what happens, and use the results to inform and refine our models. For these analog quantum computers you could make a case that, in some cases, there may be classical limits for the quantum computers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inspirational and useful comment. It is very helpful

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a very natural sense in which the "classical limit of quantum computing" does indeed exist. Of course, this depends on what exactly you mean with the question, but it's completely legitimate to ask how classical computation arises from quantum computation.

Obviously, this is not to say that quantum algorithm reduce in some limit to classical algorithms.
But you can ask in what regimes (useful) quantum algorithms are possible at all.
In the limit where decoherence and other similar factors are prominent, a quantum device cannot sustain quantum algorithms, but you might still be able to perform "classical" operations.
In other words, noise effectively constraints the space explored by the dynamics of the state. A "classical limit" can be when only "classical states" can exist in the device (that is, mixtures of states in some properly defined computational basis). Then there is no hope of performing useful quantum algorithms and the device is classical from the computational point of view.